# modified html element nested in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to change a style on a UL that is nested in a set of divs.

Here is what I have:

Html:

```
<div class='mainCat' id='List' onclick="Expand(this.id);">List</div>
  <div class='subCat'>
  <ul>
  <li>List item one</li>
   <li>List item two</li>
  <li>List item three</li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
function Expand(set)
 {
  var whichSet = document.getElementById(set);
  whichSet.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = 'block';
 }
```

and CSS:

```
 .subCat ul    
  {
  display:none;
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated. An explanation of what i'm doing wrong instead of just the answer would be really helpful as i like to learn from my mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't `set` a reserved word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chris and Jonathan Petitcolas said.

But you can also simplify it with jQuery

```
$("#list").click(function(){
    $('ul').css('display', 'block');
});
```

I would set this CSS on list, so the user can see it is clickable

```
#list {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uYuST/

Answer (score 2):

I have created a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7JWf/) with your case.

Your DOM structure is incorrect. You have a closing div tag just before `List` element. You should remove it.

Furthermore, I would have not use an inline event, as it is a bad practice. I moved it to a `addEventListener` function, which splits better DOM structure of Javascript events

So, your code becomes:

```
<div class='mainCat' id='List'>
    List
    <div class='subCat'>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

And adds the following to your Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("List").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    Expand(this.id);
}, true);
```

It should works then.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementsByTagName` inside the "set" element, but that is the `mainCat`  div, not the `subCat` div. The `ul` is not child of that div.

Also, you don't need the `this.id` part.

I changed the code, so subCat is an id instead. (Maybe you intended that `subCat` were a child of `mainCat`? if that is the case, you have an extra `</div>` next to the word `List`)

Here is a fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ndEf/

js:

```
function Expand(set) {
    var whichSet = document.getElementById(set);
    whichSet.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

html:

```
<div class='mainCat' id='List' onclick="Expand('subCat');">List</div>
<div id='subCat'>
    <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
 #subCat ul {
     display:none;
 }
```